# Regex to search for instances of a string then remove certain characters

Tags: regex

I want my regex to search for all instances of a string, then only remove specific characters from it.

e.g. to remove all `\` like `setDates(\"2020-10-28\")` to become `setDates("2020-10-28")`

but there might be multiple instances of this function that need to be updated in my content like

```
setDates(\"2020-10-28\") some additional content and text setDates(\"2020-10-23\")
```

should become

```
setDates("2020-10-28") some additional content and text setDates("2020-10-23")
```

all i've managed so far is `setDates\(*\)` which matches `setDates()` but not the `\` inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture all but double quotes and replace with backreferences:

```
Find: \b(setDates\()\\(".*?)\\("\))
Replace: $1$2
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ihSnjk/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    setDates                 'setDates'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```